# What is the purpose of EXTRA_CFLAGS?

Tags: makefile, compiler-flags

What is the intended use of `EXTRA_CFLAGS`?

I see it in some contexts but I've never understood why one wouldn't just append flags to `CFLAGS` instead of `EXTRA_CFLAGS`.

I first thought there was something to do with how make has defined its implicit rules, but this did not seem to be the case. As I understand it, there are no uses of `EXTRA_CFLAGS` in the make implicit rules, correct?

I would appreciate any enlightenment.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this available offhand?

Comment: I don't have any examples I can share. This question is also more about how this is used in general, and what coding conventions and software support/expectations that might exist for this parameter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, that's not any part of standard make or built-in make rules, so it's just a convention that some of the makefiles you're used to have used.  The reason why it's done as a separate flag is so you can use it on the command line:

```
make EXTRA_CFLAGS=-O3
```

Command line variable assignments *override* any setting of the variable inside the makefile, so appending doesn't work.  That is:

```
$ cat Makefile
CFLAGS += -Dfoo

all: ; @echo '$(CFLAGS)'

$ make CFLAGS=-Dbar
-Dbar

$ make CFLAGS+=-Dbar
-Dbar
```

both will show `-Dbar`, not `-Dfoo -Dbar`.

That's why it's a separate flag.  In automake environments, they explicitly preserve `CFLAGS` for the user to provide on the command line and all "normal" flags are put into other variables.